# How to select every pair of persons who work in the same firm and know each other?

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to construct a SPARQL query that returns every pair of persons who work in the same firm and who know each other.

I've tried:

```
SELECT distinct ?x ?y ?z
WHERE { ?x ex:knows ?y . {?x ex:worksFor ?z}} ORDER BY (?z)
```

This gives me 2 columns of employees and a column of companies. There are 3 people in each company. It should return 'pairs'. Can anyone see how I might improve the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a couple of things here.  First you also need to make sure ?y worksFor ?z.  Then, if you just want the pairs from ex:knows, select only ?x and ?y:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?y
WHERE {
   ?x ex:knows ?y .
   ?x ex:worksFor ?z .
   ?y ex:worksFor ?z .
} ORDER BY ?z
```

Comment: maybe also filter ?y != ?z

Comment: Why should we add this FILTER, given that `?y` is a person and `?z` a company?

Comment: Oh AKSW. Thank you! I could not see the logic before.

Comment: The filter is not necessary - unless persons are also companies.